# Naming a dynamic range with blanks

Tags: excel

I have a range/list with values per row. Some of the rows are blank.
I want to name the range, and the range should reach the last value (nonblank cell).

So if any cells below the range that become populated, then the range must expand to those cells, even if there are blanks between, like in scenario 2.

Do anyone have a suggestion to how to solve this?

[image: Picture provided here]

Comment: Maybe place the values in a table?  Ctrl+T to create a table.  [Overview of Excel tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)

Answer (score 1):

If the non-blank entries in that column are **numeric**, you can use:

`$M$5:INDEX($M:$M,MATCH(88^88,$M:$M))`

where `88^88` is assumed to be larger than any numeric within the range.

If the non-blank entries in that column are **non-numeric**, and **none of the blank entries are in fact null strings ("")**, you can use:

`$M$5:INDEX($M:$M,MATCH("Ω",$M:$M))`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! In reality, the nonblank entries are not numerical - but textual. Do you have any suggestions with info at hand? Sorry for not providing this info in the original question.

Comment: Are **all** the entries non-numeric, then? Or potentially a mixture of numerics and non-numerics?

Comment: @JosWoolley how could I apply this to a range of cells? For example, I have a range starting in G2, and ending in K. The data in columns G through K will always change because it is dynamic. But, the issue is that there are blank cells in J2 and K2.

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula which work both for number and text strings.

```
=Sheet1!A2:INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MAX(IF(Sheet1!A:A<>"",ROW(Sheet1!A:A),0)))
```

If you are on ***Excel-365*** then try-

```
=Sheet1!A2:INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MAX(FILTER(ROW(Sheet1!A:A),Sheet1!A:A<>"")))
```

[image]

Comment: That set-up has to process more than a **million** cells. A binary search to find the last-used row is generally thousands of times more efficient.

Comment: @JosWoolley I agree. Just a different approach if need to work with strings. In case of O365 there are more elegant ways.

Comment: The formula with `FILTER` still has to process more than a million cells, just like your first formula.